# In Pandas, how to calculate the relative probabilities of values of a column given a value of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames, `vehicles` and `casualties`, each with a common column `Accident_Index`:

```
import pandas as pd

vehicles = pd.DataFrame({'Accident_Index': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 
                         'Vehicle_Type': ['car', 'car', 'motorcyle', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car'],
                         'Sex_Driver': ['male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male']})

casualties = pd.DataFrame({'Accident_Index': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                           'Casualty_Severity': ['fatal', 'serious', 'fatal', 'light', 'fatal']})
```

For ease of visualization, here is `vehicles`:

```
   Accident_Index Sex_Driver Vehicle_Type
0               1       male          car
1               1     female          car
2               2       male    motorcyle
3               3     female          car
4               3     female          car
5               4       male          car
6               4       male          car
```

and here is `casualties`:

```
   Accident_Index Casualty_Severity
0               1             fatal
1               1           serious
2               2             fatal
3               3             light
4               4             fatal
```

I would like to calculate the how many times more likely are accidents involving male car drivers to be fatal compared to accidents involving female car drivers.

So far, I've come up with the following solution:

```
dfm = casualties.merge(vehicles, on='Accident_Index')
dfm_cars = dfm.loc[dfm.Vehicle_Type == 'car']

dfm_cars_fatal_male = dfm_cars.isin({'Casualty_Severity': ['fatal'], 'Sex_Driver': ['male']})
male_driver_involved_in_fatal_car_accident = (dfm_cars_fatal_male['Casualty_Severity'] & dfm_cars_fatal_male['Sex_Driver']).sum()

dfm_cars_fatal_female = dfm_cars.isin({'Casualty_Severity': ['fatal'], 'Sex_Driver': ['female']})
female_driver_involved_in_fatal_car_accident = (dfm_cars_fatal_female['Casualty_Severity'] & dfm_cars_fatal_female['Sex_Driver']).sum()

print(male_driver_involved_in_fatal_car_accident / female_driver_involved_in_fatal_car_accident)
```

The answer, in this case, is `3`, because there are two car accidents with a fatality, one involving a male and a female driver and one involving two male drivers.

This code doesn't seem particularly succinct, however. How could I refactor this?

Comment: Isn't the casualties bit vague. Two same accident index have differnt casualty_severity?

Comment: Bharath, this means that in a single accident involving two vehicles there were two casualties (e.g. the drivers of each vehicle).

Comment: How would you map them in the vehicles data?  First `1` is fatal and second `1` is serious? Like that. Because on merging there will be repetition of rows . Is that ohk for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `merge` + `query` + `groupby`:

```
g = casualties.merge(vehicles, on='Accident_Index')\
        .query("Vehicle_Type == 'car' and Casualty_Severity == 'fatal'")\
        .groupby('Sex_Driver').Sex_Driver.count()

g / g.sum()

Sex_Driver
female    0.25
male      0.75
Name: Sex_Driver, dtype: float64
```

---

To make this simpler, you can have query work with variables:

```
vehicle = 'car'
severity = 'fatal'
```

You can then rewrite the `query` step to:

```
query("Vehicle_Type == @vehicle and Casualty_Severity == @severity")
```

This makes it easier to reuse your code, if you want to, say, put it inside a function and test against various combinations of input.